# Execute function only when images/sounds are loaded, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, audio, load

I dynamically set image and audio sources when window/document is already loaded, e.g. I set them after user performs some manipulations on the page:

```
// image and audio set
jQuery("#image").css('background-image', 'url(../content/icons/1/18.png)').css('backgroundPosition', '0 -40px');
var myAudio = new Audio('http://domain/content/audio/1/full-18.mp3');
myAudio.pause();

// i want this part of code be executed only when images and audio is fully loaded
myAudio.play();
```

Solution number 1, isn't working

```
jQuery("#page").load(function() {});
```

Solution number 2, isn't working

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {});
```

Any other idea how to this can be solved? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specifically target the image element to check if it has loaded.

```
$('#image').load(function () {
    console.log('image loaded');
});
```

To check if the audio element is ready to be played you need to use `onloadeddata`.

```
var myAudio = new Audio('http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/edvard-grieg-peer-gynt1-morning-mood.mp3');
myAudio.onloadeddata = audioIsLoaded();

function audioIsLoaded() {
  console.log('audio is loaded');
}
```

Run the below code snippet to see this in action.

```js
$('#image').load(function() {
  alert('image loaded');
});
var myAudio = new Audio('http://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/edvard-grieg-peer-gynt1-morning-mood.mp3');
myAudio.onloadeddata = audioReady();

function audioReady() {
  alert('audio ready');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="http://armpit-wrestling.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/bret-hart.jpg">
```

Comment: I tried following code and it's not working:

var myAudio = new Audio('http://domain/content/audio/1/full-18.mp3');
jQuery(myAudio).load(function(){
   console.log('loaded'); // never gets executed
});